# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'newValue') - in chrome.storage

Tags: next.js, google-chrome-extension, tailwind-css, vercel

I am building a NextJS Static Website with TailwindCSS, without any data fetching or any complex stuff besides HTML elements.

When I shipped my site to Vercel (Production), I got the following error message in my console:

> Error in event handler: TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined
> (reading 'newValue')
> at chrome-extension://hnfanknocfeofbddgcijnmhnfnkdnaad/content.js:2:126472

When I click on content.js:

```
chrome.storage.onChanged.addListener((e) => {
  const t = e[v.ServiceWorkerStorageKey.chainSwitchedDapp];
  if (
    (chrome.storage?.local.set({
      [v.ServiceWorkerStorageKey.chainSwitchedDapp]: null,
    }),
    void 0 !== t?.newValue && null !== t.newValue && t.newValue !== t.oldValue)
  ) {
    const e = JSON.parse(t.newValue);
    new URL(e.dappURL)?.hostname === window.location.hostname &&
      e.overriddenChainId &&
      e.overriddenJsonUrl &&
      this.emitDappChainSwitch(e.overriddenChainId, e.overriddenJsonUrl);
  }
  const o = e[v.ServiceWorkerStorageKey.canSignViaExtension];
  this.emitCanSwitchAddressChanged("false" !== o.newValue);
});
```

I do not use any storage (but can not figure it out what happens inside NextJS or Vercel) and can not explain why I receive this error.

Where does this error is coming from and how can I fix this error?

Comment: Click the error in devtools to open the file at the exact location of the error. P.S. the code has several logical mistakes, but I guess it's a part of some library so you'll need to notify its author.